# I'm trying to print a certain number in perl after the value "score" and before the last number

Tags: regex, perl

```
my $find = "score";

open (TEST, "lines.txt");

my @line = <TEST>;

for (@line) {

    if ($_ =~ /$find/) {
        print split ( /score/, $_);
    }
}

close (TEST);
```

Prints out:

> 100000000 100
>
> 100000001 100
>
> 100000002 100

but i only want the the first value not the "100"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($_ =~ /$find\s*(\d+)/) {
        print "$1\n";
}
```

Comment: omg thank you so much Ron, you are the best in the entire world

Comment: This is the opposite of the behavior you described.  You said you did not want the 100.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen The OP said in a comment that their input looks like `score 1000000000 100`, so this will print the first number, not 100.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot before that I could only guess, and the use of split implied to me that score was in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

From `perldoc split`:

> Splits the string EXPR into a list of strings and returns the list in
>   list context, or the size of the list in scalar context.

`split ( /score/, $_);` returns a list of strings which you then print. Given your output I am assuming your input file lines look like this:

```
100000000 score100
```

If you only want the first value then you should capture that result from split and print only that. You can use `undef` to ignore the value you do not wish to capture:

```
my ($value, undef) = split /score/; # split works on $_ by default
print $value;
```

Another approach would be to not use split and instead pattern match against each line with a regular expression capture group:

```
if (my ($value) =~ /(\w+) $find/) {
    print $value;
}
```

Comment: my print comes out like this: score 1000000000 100                                     but i want the 100000000 to only print, i looked all over but some how i can't find.

Comment: I just explained how to do this.

Comment: I know but somehow is not working.     :(   don't know what to do. i tried it but nothing

Comment: Show us a few lines of the input.  Is **score** before or in-between or after the 2 sets of numbers?

Comment: if you print, it shows like this: "100000000 100" and i tried to do it how Hunter said but it didn't work. i don't know what I'm doing wrong. Score is before the 1st set of numbers, like this: "score 1000000000 100"

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of split is wrong.

Though this is not the best way, I will correct your code itself, instead of suggesting better ways:

```
my $find = "score";

open (TEST, "lines.txt");

my @line = <TEST>;

for (@line) {

    if ($_ =~ /($find)(\s+)(\d+)(\s+)(\d+)/) {
        print $3; $1 will be Score. $2 will be space. $3 will be your value etc.
    }
}

close (TEST);
```